# Images In Xcode Storyboard Randomly Get Distorted

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, image, xcode-storyboard

I am new to swift/xcode/iOS development. I've created a project in xcode and I'm having the weirdest bug affect me. When I launch xcode, the storyboard images appear to be distorted. I can close xcode, re-launch and sometimes they will be fine and sometimes they will not be fine. What would cause these images to distort? When I run the app both on a device and simulator the images are fine and have no issues at all. Why only on the storyboard do these images get distorted?

[image: Storyboard View]

[image: View Controller View]

EDIT: The possible duplicate question is about question marks displaying whereas in my Xcode it is about the images being distorted. I came across that answer while searching but since they said it was question marks I didn't think it was related to me. Anyone now searching for distorted images will come across this question and find the right info. Thanks to all

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It loads in the original image, because you have no "screen scale" showing the @2x or @3x image . When you run it in the device, it loads the correct @2x or @3x depending on the **device scale**.

Comment: Thank you a million!! I was thinking it was related to having different scaled images but wasn't sure. Do you recommend an easy way to take an image and create all the needed scaled images? I found this site: http://assets.codly.io/ and was going to try that out. Thank you again so much

Comment: @MatthewZourelias **In my own taste** I do this manually , calculating is pretty easy. If your original is 10pixels, the 2x is 20pixels, the 3x is 30 pixels. It takes more time doing this manually, but I like the control :) however, there are many solutions that create the correct pixels for you, but its not that hard to calculate it as I mentioned. Just make sure your image pixels is ALWAYS able to multiple by 2 and 3 correctly on either the height or the width, and when you do the calculations multiple with the width if you chosen the width, **or** the height if you go with height.

Comment: @MatthewZourelias Grate explanation

Comment: @sneak you have been a lifesaver, thank you a ton for this info. I did not know that 2x and 3x are essential 2 times and 3 times the original. Great knowledge to know :)

Comment: @MatthewZourelias It is the key to get pixel perfect sharp images! :) Don't forget to mark this as the answer if this was helpful to you and solved your problems, so other people also can see it! Thanks and GL :)

Comment: @sneak I just was able to mark it as an answer, thank you again for taking time out of your day to answer a question for a newb like me :)

Comment: @MatthewZourelias NP man, feel free to ask anything you need help with. Just make sure you check for duplicates before and read through the  stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask its all green! :)